# /bin/sh: 1: aarch64-vtlinux-linux-g++ --sysroot=/opt/vtlinux/sysroots/aarch64-vtlinux-linux: not found

Tags: c, makefile, cross-compiling, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to configure for my Eclipse CDT but i faced the following problems

```
/bin/sh: 1: aarch64-xxlinux-linux-g++  --sysroot=/opt/xxlinux/sysroots/aarch64-xxlinux-linux: not found
```

So if i am not mistaken, the mistake is with my "aarch64-xxlinux-linux-g++" not being able to be located by the compiler

However, I have already set Environment Variable "PATH" to the directory where aarch64-xxlinux-linux-g++ can be found

I have set CXX environment variable to be following

```
Environment Variable: CXX   Value: "aarch64-xxlinux-linux-g++ --sysroot=$(SDKTARGETSYSROOT)"
Environment Variable: PATH   Value: /opt/xxlinux/sysroots/x86_64-xxlinuxsdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-xxlinux-linux:$(PATH)
```

/opt/xxlinux/sysroots/x86_64-xxlinuxsdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-xxlinux-linux is where the "aarch64-xxlinux-linux-g++" is located
.

Is it the only place I need to set the variables for?

Regards

Comment: Did you restart Eclipse CDT from a new shell, ensuring the new environment variables are read?

Comment: @yoonghm: Restarted the eclipse CDT a few times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not quote your entire environment variable value.

You are trying to run a command with an argument: that's two "words".  By adding quotes to the value you're creating a single word and the shell thinks you want to run a program named `aarch64-xxlinux-linux-g++ --sysroot=$(SDKTARGETSYSROOT)` which doesn't exist.

If you are worried about `SDKTARGETSYSROOT` containing whitespace (which is a valid concern), you should quote just that value not the entire thing:

```
Environment Variable: CXX   Value: aarch64-xxlinux-linux-g++ --sysroot="$(SDKTARGETSYSROOT)"
```

Comment: It really worked!!